# I mounted an Ubuntu VHD in Disk Manager on Windows 10 can this be cloned to USB and booted from?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, usb

Because the GPU cannot be accessed in Hyper-V, I'm going to need to create a separate means of booting my computer into my Linux image. I'd rather have the image stored on a removable USB so I'm trying to get my Ubuntu virtual machine onto a bootable USB so that I can just boot my computer off the USB and run Linux when I need to. I have my VHD mounted in disk manager but I'm searching endlessly for a way to clone this disk in its current file system format to the USB within a Windows 10 session if possible. I can't get to the USB from the VM either so using the Linux session to clone to USB is also impossible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may use any cloning software to clone the attached VHD to the USB device.
The result USB will only work for booting computers that are compatible with
the VHD image.

For example, see the EaseUS article
[Easy VHD to Physical Disk Solution](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/vhd-to-physical-disk.html).